# Bash: sort rows within a file by timestamp

Tags: bash

I am new to bash scripting and I have written a script to match regex and output lines to print to a file.

However, each line contains multiple columns, one of which is the timestamp column, which appears in the form YYYYMMDDHHMMSSTTT (to millisecond) as shown below.

```
20180301050630663,ABC,,,,,,,,,,
20180301050630664,ABC,,,,,,,,,,
20180301050630665,ABC,,,,,,,,,,
20180301050630666,ABC,,,,,,,,,,
20180301050630667,ABC,,,,,,,,,,
20180301050630668,ABC,,,,,,,,,,
20180301050630663,ABC,,,,,,,,,,
20180301050630665,ABC,,,,,,,,,,
20180301050630661,ABC,,,,,,,,,,
20180301050630662,ABC,,,,,,,,,,
```

My code is written as follow:

```
awk -F "," -v OFS=","'{if($2=="ABC"){print}}' < $i>> "$filename"
```

How can I modify my code such that it can sort the rows by timestamp (YYYYMMDDHHMMSSTTT) in ascending order before printing to file?

Comment: Can you use `sort filename`?

Comment: Are you using `gawk` or POSIX `awk`?

Comment: I believe i am just using `awk`. Is there a way to check ? What is POSIX `awk` ?

Comment: POSIX  `awk` is required for a Unix to have POSIX qualifications. `gawk` is the GNU version of `awk` and is a superset of `awk`. `gawk` is the default on Linux. POSIX `awk` is the default on BSD, OS X, HP UX, etc. `gawk` is easily installed on non-Linux systems.

Comment: I am using ubuntu in window 10. So I believe mine is just POSIX `awk`.

Comment: `awk -v` will tell you that, but I think ubuntu on Windows will have the GNU toolset including the GNU version of `awk`

Answer (score 5):

You can use a very simple sort command, e.g.

```
sort yourfile
```

If you want to insure `sort` only looks at the datestamp, you can tell sort to only use the first command separated field as your sorting criteria, e.g.

```
sort -t, -k1 yourfile
```

**Example Use/Output**

With your data save in a file named `log`, you could do:

```
$ sort -t, -k1 log
20180301050630661,ABC,,,,,,,,,,
20180301050630662,ABC,,,,,,,,,,
20180301050630663,ABC,,,,,,,,,,
20180301050630663,ABC,,,,,,,,,,
20180301050630664,ABC,,,,,,,,,,
20180301050630665,ABC,,,,,,,,,,
20180301050630665,ABC,,,,,,,,,,
20180301050630666,ABC,,,,,,,,,,
20180301050630667,ABC,,,,,,,,,,
20180301050630668,ABC,,,,,,,,,,
```

Let me know if you have any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a pipeline.

```
awk -F "," '$2=="ABC"' < "$i" |
sort -n >> "$filename"
```

In the general case, to sort on column 234. try `sort -t, -k234,234n`

Notice alse the quoting around `"$i"`, like you already have around `"$filename"`, and the simplifications of the Awk script.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `gawk` you can do:

```
$ awk -F "," -v OFS="," '$2=="ABC"{a[$1]=$0}         # Filter lines that have "ABC"
                         END{ # set the sort method
                             PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"   
                             for (e in a) print a[e] # traverse the array of lines
                         }' file
```

An alternative is to use `sed` and `sort`:

```
sed -n '/^[0-9]*,ABC,/p' file | sort -t, -k1 -n
```

Keep in mind that both of these methods are unrelated to the shell used. Bash is just executing the tools (`sed`, `awk`, `sort`, etc) that are otherwise part of the OS.

Bash itself *could* do the sort in pure Bash but it would be **long** and **slow**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer . Do you mind explaining a bit more in your code ? I am trying to learn a bit about bash as well. Thanks.